# Simplifies Chines(GB2312) character issue- Solaris Weblogic 10.3

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, weblogic, gb2312

i am trying to fetch and update simplified chinese character(GB2312) from database , Update part is  works fine in weblogic 10.3 windows machine , but it fails(junk character) in weblogic 10.3 Solaris machine  , but Fetching and displaying chines character is working fine in both environments

**Fetching DAO**

```
  while (rs.next()) {           
                    Base64 base64 = new Base64();
                    byte[] notesByte = base64.encode(rs
                            .getBytes("notes"));                
    }
```

**UI (Android)**

```
     byte[] notes= Base64.decode(notesByteStr , Base64.DEFAULT);
       notesText.setText(new String(notes, "GB2312")); // Displaying chines char

     notesByte=  Base64.encode(notesText.getText().toString().trim().getBytes("GB2312"),  Base64.DEFAULT) // send to db
```

**Update DAO**

```
 getSession().createSQLQuery(notesUpdateQuery)
                    .setParameter(0, new String(base64.decode(notesByte)))
                    .executeUpdate();
```

**note**: Source txt file encoding : UTF-8

Comment: I've answered the question as best I can, but "it fails" gives us no information about what's actually going wrong. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: actually  updated with junk character like ?????

Comment: Do you mean you *actually* get question marks, or that you get other characters that you weren't expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well yes, look at this in your Update DAO:

```
new String(base64.decode(notesByte))
```

That's using the platform default encoding to convert the base64-decoded byte array into a string. The base64-decoded byte array is actually text encoded in GB2312 - *not* in the platform default encoding.

To convert it properly, you need to specify the same encoding everywhere:

```
new String(base64.decode(notesByte), "GB2312")
```

Comment: i tried new String(base64.decode(notesByte), "GB2312") in my dao again faild (junk charter) in both environment

Comment: You'll need to give more information - and more diagnostics - then. The problem I identified in this answer was definitely *a* problem, but apparently not all of it. It's hard to understand the data flow from just those three snippets - please edit your question to explain *exactly* what's going on, and also what diagnostics you've perfromed.

Comment: problem solved with (new String(base64.decode(notesByte), "cp1252"))

Comment: @Arun: Well that sounds like something was using Windows-CP1252 when converting to base64... have you identified *where* that's happening? (I'd strongly advise you to change it if possible to use UTF-8...)

Comment: the problem is one more windows legacy application is using that field , we are just consumer for that field